# Python : word frequency in a file

Tags: python-2.7

I've created a simple word count program in python which reads a text file, counts the word frequency and writes the result to another file. 
now The problem is that if i want to search "windows" and text file contain a word "xwindows" then it count it also.

```
import sys
import glob
import errno
files = glob.glob('w.asm')
the_count =['windows']
for name in files:
    with open(name) as f:
        print "Occurences in file -- %s " % name
        contents = f.read()
        print contents
        for number in the_count:
            print "windows occured-", contents.count(number)
```

w.asm file contains

```
windows
iwindows
qwindows
hwindows
kwindows
windows
windows
windowsh
wwindows
windows
iwindows
qwindows
hwindows
kwindows
```

output is

```
Occurences in file -- w.asm 

windows
iwindows
qwindows
hwindows
kwindows
windows
windows
windowsh
wwindows
windows
iwindows
qwindows
hwindows
kwindows
windows occured- 14
```

so the actual output which i want is 4 because windows occurred actually 4 times but code is giving 14....

so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

14 is actually correct, since `windowsh` and such contain the substring `winows`. A simple fix is to first split the file by words, then call `count()`:

```
for name in files:
    with open(name) as f:
        print "Occurences in file -- %s " % name
        contents = f.read().split() # <--- split
        print contents
        for number in the_count:
            print "windows occured-", contents.count(number)
```